# how to have kivy button wait for user to speak to successfully run try block?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, speech-recognition, kivy-language

I am having an issue where when the button is pressed and the user says the command the exception is still run. I have attempted on_press and on_release and haven't came to a solution.

Here is the code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import speech_recognition as sr

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Hello, Im Jinx'))

        self.speak = Button(text="Speak", font_size=40)
        self.speak.bind(on_release=self.command)
        self.add_widget(self.speak)
   
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    def command(self):
        try:
            with sr.Microphone as source:
                voice = MyGrid.r.listen(source)
                command = MyGrid.r.recognize_google(voice)
                command = command.lower()
                if 'Jinx' in command:
                    command = command.replace('Jinx', '')
                    print("Jinx's Listening")
        except:
            print('Sorry, try again.')


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: I remember there have sth like `timeout` for the `r.listen()` , is it sth you are looking for ? ref. : [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) [GitHub Repo. Examples](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/tree/master/examples)

Comment: Just change your definition of the `command()` method to `def command(self, *args):`.